# Create a temporary image from URL not working

Tags: android, json

- List item

I'm loading some images from a URL by using JSON and opening them in full size in a new Activity.
In that Activity I want to share them by using a `ShareActionProvider`.

Some questions on Stack Overflow suggest downloading them first as a temporary file, but it's not working with my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    path = i.getStringExtra(TAG_FILEIMG);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.full_screen, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

    return true;
}

public File getTempFile(Context context, String url) {

    url = path;
    try {
        String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
        file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;

}

private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, file);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");


    return shareIntent;

}
```

full_screen.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.habitodigital.FullScreenActivity" >

    <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>

</menu>
```

*path* is the JSON image path I use to load images by using an `ImageLoader`.
Is this temporary file creation code correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an empty file here.

```
public File getTempFile(Context context, String url) {

url = path;
try {
    String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
    file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return file;

}
```

What you should do is download the image from the website and write it into that file.

You can use [FileOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29) to write on the file.

Comment: Thank u @torque203 ..I got it using this android guide https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sharing-Content-with-Intents